# Can I assign values to class variables via iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use a list of values to alter a bunch of class values that I added to another (temporary) list.

```
class game_events():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stage = 0
        self.rules = False

saved_vars = [12, True]

game = game_events()
i = 0
for x in [game.stage, game.rules]:
    x = saved_vars[i]
    i+=1
```

It seems like everything is working, but that only the temporary list is being altered, like a decoy.

**Desired results:**

game.stage == 12

game.rules is True

**Actual results:**

game.stage == 0

game.rules is False

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `x = saved_vars[i]`, you're rebinding the variable `x`, not modifying the `game` object where it's previous value came from. If you want to modify just a few attributes on `game`, it's a whole lot easier to just do so directly:

```
game.stage, game.rules = saved_vars[0:2]
```

If you have a whole lot of attributes to go through, rather than just two in this example, you might return to your loop idea, but you'd need to do it differently. Rather than an assignment, you'd need to use `setattr`. And that means you'll need to specify the name of the attributes as strings, not with dotted notation:

```
for attr, value in zip(['stage', 'rules'], saved_vars):
    setattr(game, attr, value)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm having issues with comparisons since trying this (issues that I don't have if I assign each value manually/individually). I'll have to figure that out, but this is what I was looking for.